# "DAL exception occured" error when using SAP B1 query to generate number in Produmex

Tags: sql, hana

I have defined already written Batch Number generation query in SAP B1, but as we use HANA database, I have converted it.

At first, query looked like this:

SELECT T0.[CardCode] + '-' + CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 112) AS 'BXBATNUM' 
FROM OPOR T0 WHERE T0.[DocEntry] = [%4]

then, I converted it to HANA syntax

SELECT T0."CardCode" || '-' || cast(current_date as varchar) || '/' || cast (current_time as varchar)  AS "BXBATNUM" 
FROM OPOR T0 WHERE T0."DocEntry" = [%4]

P.S I Also get this error on different screen:

"DAL Exception occured ---> System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException: ERROR [S1000] [SAP AG][LIBODBCHDB32 DLL][HDBODBC32] General error;260 invalid column name: current_date: line 1 col 39 (at pos 38)"

When I am trying to generate number with this query in another software called "Produmex Scan" - I get "DAL exception occured" error.

What can be done in this matter?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

HANA is case sensitive; I think "current_date" should be "CURRENT_DATE". Please see the following SAP help page for the CURRENT_DATE function.

https://help.sap.com/viewer/4fe29514fd584807ac9f2a04f6754767/2.0.02/en-US/20ddfe5d75191014af50837e2818462d.html

Hope that fixes the error